# Adding a 10px frame around a colored image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I am trying to add a 10 px boarder around my colored image.
I have the following code to do that:

```
myRGB = mpimg.imread(" ")
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(myRGB)
plt.show()
```

```
framed_color = np.zeros(np.add(myRGB.shape, tuple([20,20,0])))
framed_color[10:myRGB.shape[0]+10,10:myRGB.shape[1]+10] = myRGB
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(framed_color)
```

After I run the code in the second chunk, my image become super bright, I cannot see the image, but the boarder is still here. I am able to do the boarder thing on gray image, because that case my tuple would be just 20,20, I don't need a third dimension.

I just want to know is there anyway to show image the way it supposed to be with boarder? Or it has to be gray image if I have to do it this way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`plt.imshow(framed_color.astype(np.uint8)) will do.`